# Have watch exit, when the output does not change anymore

Tags: shell, watch

Is there a simple way to have watch cancel, if the output does NOT change anymore?

`watch -g` will exit once the output changes, but I want the opposite. So watch the output as long as it is still changing every interval or every x seconds or similar, and have it quit once the output stays the same for a while.

Comment: Depending on what you are doing in `watch` this can be "difficult but possible" or "really difficult". The first thing i can think of is using `tee` to copy stdout to a file in `/tmp` and using `stat` in a loop to check the mtime. But what is actually running in your `watch` ?. **Edit:** I have to correct myself, each run through `watch` will change the mtime, even if the output doesn't change. Instead of `stat` you could use `md5sum` to check if it stays the same.

Comment: @Garo thanks for the hints. In this specific instance it was tail to monitor the last lines of a file. I am aware that in this case there would be other methods but was wondering if there is a general solution not depending on the actual command being watched.